# replace headers in csv file and writing selected columns using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, csv

On a weekly basis, I need to replace the header in a csv file (that has a date dependent name) and delete two of the columns. I though the easiest way would be to write a new csv file with the pertinent information(i.e. without columns k and l).
This is how my code looks like:

```
import csv
import calendar
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
tuesday = date.today() - timedelta(3)
p = tuesday.strftime('%Y%m%d') 

us_csv = 'E:/' + "TEST_us_" + p + ".csv"

HIn = "a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, l"
HOut = "A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H"

fIn= open ('us_csv', 'r')

HeaderIn = fIn.readline()
HeaderOut = HeaderIn.replace(HIn, HOut, 1)

fOut = open ('E:/Abase/usStats.csv', 'w')

fOut.write(HeaderOut + '\n')
    for line in fIn
    fOut.write(line)
fOut.close
```

The new csv is empty. I read most of the similar questions, but I simply can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is the spacing in your example correct? Your for loop looks indented for no reason (it's not within a control statement of any kind), and your `fOut.write(line)` is not indented further than the for, which means it would execute after the loop completed? Also, is this all of the code or just a relevant snippet?

Comment: No, the indent just copied incorrectly. And this is just a snippet of a larger script - basically this csv is one of the inputs that will go to update a feature service in GIS. However, once I get to arcpy, I can probably finish what I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. I like to use `writelines` so I can do all the writing at once. It might be possible that you were running into trouble because you had two files open. I'm not sure. To be safe I always open and close files immediately using a block as shown.

This might not be necessary, but I tend to split up the rows into lists of values so I can do the manipulations I need. I'm using the csv module to this for me. You can see here I used list splicing to remove the last two columns of each row. Then I join them back together.

```
import os
import argparse
import operator
import csv

def main():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser (description="Removes last two columns and renames headers.")
    p.add_argument("origfile", help="Path of original file")
    p.add_argument("newfile", help="Path of new file.")
    args = p.parse_args()

    with open(args.origfile) as f:
        raw_rows = f.read().splitlines()

    new_header_row = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H\n" # Don't put spaces

    # for easier manipulation I like to split the row into a list values
    # then rejoin them later after I've changed or removed what I needed
    rows = csv.reader(raw_rows)

    newfile_lines = [new_header_row]
    newfile_lines.extend(",".join(row[:-2]) + "\n" for row in rows)

    with open(args.newfile, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(newfile_lines)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I ran this on:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

And got:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```